Error: `align` attribute can only be applied to a struct, enum, or union
How can i align member of struct to a specific boundary. One motivation would be to disable false sharing of cache lines.
Consider this example:
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;
pub struct Foo {
    id: String,
    read: AtomicBool,
    #[repr(align(64))]
    write: AtomicBool
}

error[E0517]: attribute should be applied to a struct, enum, function, associated function, or union
 --> src/lib.rs:5:12
  |
5 |     #[repr(align(64))]
  |            ^^^^^^^^^
6 |     write: AtomicBool
  |     ----------------- not a struct, enum, function, associated function, or union

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0517`.


Create a wrapper type:
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;

#[repr(align(64))]
struct CacheAligned<T>(T);

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Foo {
    id: String,
    read: AtomicBool,
    write: CacheAligned<AtomicBool>,
}

You should also use #[repr(C)] if you are interested in a specific layout; the layout is unspecified otherwise.

If it is not too inconvenient, you could embed the atomic bool in its own struct with proper alignment.
If you want some kind of control on the order of the members in the Foo struct, repr(C) helps.
In the example below, playing with repr(align(64)) shows the situations of false sharing (or not).
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool;

#[repr(align(64))] // comment this to test
#[derive(Default)]
struct AlignedAtomicBool(AtomicBool);

#[repr(C)] // preserve order of members
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Foo {
    read: AlignedAtomicBool,
    id: String,
    write: AlignedAtomicBool,
}

fn test_false_sharing(f: &Foo) {
    let addr1 = &f.read.0 as *const _ as usize;
    let addr2 = &f.write.0 as *const _ as usize;
    if addr1 / 64 == addr2 / 64 {
        println!("false sharing");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::default();
    test_false_sharing(&foo);
    for n in 1..100 {
        let v = Vec::from_iter((0..n).map(|_| Foo::default()));
        for f in v.iter() {
            test_false_sharing(f);
        }
    }
}


Thanks for the test_false_sharing. It is quite useful.
